# React router v5 renders only index page on all routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

**ISSUE**

- any route written manually in URL or triggered by button renders only index page (route name is changing, content of the page is always content of index)

**App.js** (handling all the main functions from the app)

```
// Exporting my router and passing all states/functions from App
 
<div className="App">
                    <Routes
                        ........
                        ........
                        ........
                        onRemove={onRemove}
                        setCartOpen={setCartOpen}
                        cartOpen={cartOpen}
                        .......
                        .......
/>
                </div>
```

**Router** (example of how my routes work)

```
export default function Routes({....., ....., onRemove,setCartOpen,cartOpen,..... })

 <Router>
            <Header
                countCartItems={cartItems.length}
                cartItems={cartItems}
                onAdd={onAdd}
                onRemove={onRemove}
                setCartOpen={setCartOpen}
            />
            <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route
                        path={baseRouteUrl + '/'}
                        component={(props) => (
                            <IndexPage
                                {...props}
                                .......
                                .......
                                onRemove={onRemove}
                                setCartOpen={setCartOpen}
                                cartOpen={cartOpen}
                                .......
                                .......
                            />
                        )}>
                  </Route>
                <Route
                    path={baseRouteUrl + '/about'}
                    component={About}
                ></Route>
                <Route
                    path={baseRouteUrl + ''}
                    component={NotFound}
                ></Route>
.......
```

And **Index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <QueryClientProvider client={client}>
            <ChakraProvider>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <App />
                </BrowserRouter>
            </ChakraProvider>
        </QueryClientProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**NOTE**

- Before trying to pass props in the routes the router was working just fine

The reason I decided to structure my app this way is because I need my `Header` to be exported on all pages with all the functionalities.

Is there anything I should do in a different way? I know it might be a little messy, so I'll be grateful to learn how to handle it cleaner and most important, how to make it work so all routes will render the correct pages.

Answer (score 1):

react router does partial matching so '/' is partial from '/about' when using exact it will disable the partial matching and will get the correct path

```
<Route
    exact
    path={baseRouteUrl + '/'}
    component={(props) => (
    <IndexPage
    {...props}
    .......
    .......
    onRemove={onRemove}
    setCartOpen={setCartOpen}
    cartOpen={cartOpen}
    .......
    .......
    />
    )}>
    </Route>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Just like in most languages, a switch will match and runs the first thing it runs into.

In this case, it's matching your default path and rendering that one first.

One of the way to deal with this is to set `exact` to true

`<Route exact path={...}... />`

Comment: Thanks @NicholasWong, I added `exact` to my route, but it did not solve the issue :(

Comment: Could it be `baseRouteUrl` messing things up? From my understanding that's not needed and a simple `<Route exact path="/" ... />` would be all that I'll need for the default base path.

Comment: I found what was wrong @NicholasWong - I added `exact` as you suggested, but I had one route with `:slug` - I deleted that one and it works. But now I have an issue of not rendering nested routes - I need to append nested route to my index page component - so now `..path={baseUrl + "/:slug} component={(props) => <IndexPage {...props} />` does not work